# How to only accept letters in my scanner java

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

My code has a scanner in it. I want my scanner to only accept alphabets and to repeat the user input if a number is detected. Any ideas about how I could do this?

Here is my sample code:

```
if (isFull() == false) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Passenger p = new Passenger();

    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    p.setName(input.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter surname: ");
    p.setSurname(input.nextLine());

    queueArray[last] = p;
    last = (last + 1) % queueArray.length;
    System.out.println("Passenger entered is now in position " + last);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex patterns to determine if the user input is number or string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    String a = input.nextLine();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println("all characters are digits!");
    }
    else System.out.println("its a normal string");
}
```